# How to manage authentication securly using websocket with expiration in mind

Tags: authentication, cookies, websocket

first post here!

So I'm writing a web application using websocket and it needs authentication.
I use python (with fastapi) and vuejs but I don't think that's really important.

The thing is I want to use JWT with cookie for the security it provides (XSS and CSRF protection).
But websocket does not seems to work nicely with cookies:

- When the client log in using http, server returns a JWT token in a cookie
- The client can then open a websocket connection. At this time the cookie is sent so I can still check if the user has valid token
- But I cannot send cookie when sending websocket messages through the ws connection.

So when the JWT token expires, I can't really do anything

I've looked around and found some possibilities, but I don't think one either is good enough:

- I can let the websocket connection open and still allow ws messages => this bypass the expiration part of JWT
- I can close the websocket connection when the token expire and the client would renew the token shortly after => the client might miss some messages between deconnection and reconnection
- I can use localstorage insted of a cookie => but I would be exposed to XSS attack

Did I missed something or is this the only options?
If so, do you think one of theses possibilities is better?

Thanks in advance for your help and please tell me if something is unclear

PS: Sorry for the poor english, I'm french (honhon baguette)